# Как отнять от текущей даты три дня?

Tags: php, дата, время

Задача такова: получаю дату в переменную `$dat = date("Y-m-d");`

Допустим, сегодня получилось `2016-01-03`. Надо отнять от нее 3 дня. Естественно получится `2015-12-31` и естественно, если отнимем два дня, то получится `2016-01-01`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то простой способ провести такую манипуляцию?
Я попробовал заморочиться с `explode("-",$dat);`, а потом уже вычислять, но получилось СЛИШКОМ громоздкое уравнение. Хотелось бы попроще. Я слышал, что можно как-то дату модифицировать более простым способом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте функцию [mktime()](http://www.php.su/mktime)

```
$date = getdate(mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 3, date('Y')));
```

или

```
$date = date("M-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 3, date('Y')));
```

Answer (score 11):

Есть [расширения для работы с датой и временем](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.datetime.php).

Приведу цитату из документации, которая указывает на частую ошибку программистов:

> Убедительная просьба принимать во внимание, что эти функции
>   зависят от региональных настроек сервера. При работе с этими функциями
>   следует обращать внимание на високосные года и переход на летнее время
>   (Например, следует использовать `$date = strtotime('+7 days', $date)`,
>   но не `$date += 7*24*60*60`).

Ваша задача решается за два шага двумя способами.

**Первый**

```
/* (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7) */
$date = new DateTime('-3 days');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Второй**

```
/* (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) */
$date = strtotime('-3 days');
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Answer (score 6):

[strtotime](http://php.ru/manual/function.strtotime.html) преобразует текстовое представление даты на английском языке в метку времени Unix.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("-3 day", $date);
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно сократить до двух строчек. В функцию `strtotime` вторым параметром передается по умолчанию текущее время. Следовательно, первую и вторую строчку из вашего ответа можно удалить, а из третьей убрать передачу второго параметра.

Comment: Я старался человеку подробно объяснить. Если на то уж пошло,  можно и в одну строчку сократить (-:

Comment: Спасибо огромной у всех классные ответы)

Answer (score 5):

В одну строку это делается так:

```php
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-3 day"));
```